# How can I better organize my TShark output to make it more readable?

Tags: powershell, formatting, tshark

I am attempting to make a power shell script that I can take a tshark output file from a capture on a specified interface and perform analytics on it. I am currently able to specify the interface to capture and the amount of time to perform the capture, but the output is all condensed into what appears to be a single line.

How would I format the tshark output and the statistics table below to make it more readable, or back into the format that tshark originally shows when you run the tool on its own?

```
#Capture the Client Subnets for the Tap/SPAN

param([string[]]$subnets)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

#Capture variables
$shark = ".\tshark.exe"
$flagshark = "-i"
$interfaceshark = ".\tshark.exe -D"

Invoke-Expression $interfaceshark

$userinterface = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the number beside the interface that you would like to capture?'
$time = Read-Host -Prompt 'How much time would you like to capture for the assessment?'

#Run Tshark

& $shark -i "$userinterface" -a duration:"$time" -w testingoutput.pcap

foreach ($nets in $subnets) {
$analysis = '.\tshark.exe -r testingoutput.pcap -2 -R "ip.addr == $nets" -z conv,ip'
$result = Invoke-Expression $analysis
Write-Host $result | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

This is the output that I am wanting:

```
   84   0.707630 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 → 50000 Len=161
   85   0.751054 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 116 57560 → 50052 Len=74
   86   0.751055 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   87   0.751055 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   88   0.751057 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   89   0.751057 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   90   0.751058 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   91   0.751198 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   92   0.751199 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1097 57560 → 50052 Len=1055
   93   0.751199 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 1096 57560 → 50052 Len=1054
   94   0.751200 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 304 57560 → 50052 Len=262
   95   0.752471 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 93 54450 → 50000 Len=51
   96   0.767686 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 → 50000 Len=161
   97   0.827670 52.112.6.179 → 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 → 50000 Len=161
97 packets captured
==============================================================================
IPv4 Conversations
Filter:<No Filter>
                                               |       <-      | |       ->      | |     Total     |    Relative    |   Duration   |
                                               | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes |      Start     |              |
10.201.0.49          <-> 52.112.6.179              78     26413      11      6395      89     32808     0.000000000         0.8277
10.201.0.1           <-> 224.0.0.10                 0         0       2       160       2       160     0.379198000         0.1439
10.201.0.49          <-> 165.225.34.36              1       107       1        54       2       161     0.624698000         0.0405
10.201.0.16          <-> 239.255.255.250            0         0       1       216       1       216     0.088173000         0.0000
10.201.0.40          <-> 239.255.255.250            0         0       1       216       1       216     0.090642000         0.0000
==============================================================================
```

This is what I am currently getting:

```
91   0.549731 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  STUN 130 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 206.27.171.242:50000 user: c6Si:m9Dx    92   0.565386 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161    93   0.584513 5
2.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 116 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=74    94   0.584513 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 177 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=135    95   0.584513 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 156 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=114    96   0.584513 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201
.0.49  UDP 219 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=177    97   0.584514 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 395 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=353    98   0.584514 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 395 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=353    99   0.584516 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 395 57560 
â†’ 50052 Len=353   100   0.584516 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 394 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=352   101   0.584661 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 411 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=369   102   0.625153 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161   1
03   0.659342 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 1196 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=1154   104   0.686102 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161   105   0.731077 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 116 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=74   106   0.731077 52.112
.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 177 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=135   107   0.731078 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 156 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=114   108   0.731078 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 213 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=171   109   0.731079 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.4
9  UDP 403 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=361   110   0.731079 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 403 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=361   111   0.731079 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 403 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=361   112   0.731080 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 403 57560 â†’ 
50052 Len=361   113   0.731081 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 403 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=361   114   0.731086 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 400 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=358   115   0.731086 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 419 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=377   116  
 0.745221 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161   117   0.784472 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 450 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=408   118   0.805436 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161   119   0.855067 52.112.6.17
9 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 116 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=74   120   0.855068 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 177 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=135   121   0.855068 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 156 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=114   122   0.855069 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP
 210 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=168   123   0.855069 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 442 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=400   124   0.855070 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 442 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=400   125   0.855071 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 458 57560 â†’ 50052 
Len=416   126   0.865431 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161   127   0.924276 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 222 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=180   128   0.925249 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 203 54450 â†’ 50000 Len=161   129   0.930
466  10.201.0.49 â†’ 165.225.34.36 TCP 235 1091 â†’ 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1026 Len=181   130   0.985159 52.112.6.179 â†’ 10.201.0.49  UDP 116 57560 â†’ 50052 Len=74 ================================================================================ IPv4
 Conversations Filter:<No Filter>                                                |       <-      | |       ->      | |     Total     |    Relative    |   Duration   |                                                | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes | | Frames
  Bytes |      Start     |              | 10.201.0.49          <-> 52.112.6.179             121     73200       4       742     125     73942     0.000000000         0.9852 10.201.0.49          <-> 52.112.67.77               2       250       1        54    
   3       304     0.280012000         0.0001 10.201.0.1           <-> 224.0.0.10                 0         0       1        80       1        80     0.494976000         0.0000 10.201.0.49          <-> 165.225.34.36              0         0       1       235
       1       235     0.930466000         0.0000 ================================================================================
```

Comment: `tshark` output seems to be UTF8 encoded. Line ending may also be Unix type.

Comment: Would changing the tshark output to a UNIX supported output make it line up better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Write-Host $result | Format-Table -AutoSize` to `$result`. Once you've dumped the content of `$result` to the host you can't any longer pipe it to the `Format-Table` cmdlet. Using `Format-Table` makes no sense, since you receive a `string`-array where you have to split up the several columns to make it use for `Format-Table`.

To convert the given strings to an array of PowerShell custom-objects I came up with:

```
PS C:\> $result = iex '.\tshark.exe -r C:\temp\test.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e _ws.col.Info -E header=y -E separator="," -E quote=d -E occurrence=f' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now `$result` is an array of PowerShell objects. If I dump the first object of the array:

```
PS C:\> $result | Select-Object -First 1

frame.number : 1
frame.time   : May 14, 2019 06:59:40.011932000 W. Europe Daylight Time
eth.src      : b0:fa:eb:1e:8f:a1
eth.dst      : 00:50:56:a4:24:eb
ip.src       : 172.22.21.50
ip.dst       : 10.22.23.98
ip.proto     : 17
_ws.col.Info : 58842 ÔåÆ 3389 Len=12
```

You see that the object has several properties. To see all available object properties we can use the `Get-Member`cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> $result[0] | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

    Name         MemberType   Definition
    ----         ----------   ----------
    Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()
    GetType      Method       type GetType()
    ToString     Method       string ToString()
    eth.dst      NoteProperty string eth.dst=00:50:56:a4:24:eb
    eth.src      NoteProperty string eth.src=b0:fa:eb:1e:8f:a1
    frame.number NoteProperty string frame.number=1
    frame.time   NoteProperty string frame.time=May 14, 2019 06:59:40.011932000 W. Europe Daylight Time
    ip.dst       NoteProperty string ip.dst=10.22.23.98
    ip.proto     NoteProperty string ip.proto=17
    ip.src       NoteProperty string ip.src=172.22.21.50
    _ws.col.Info NoteProperty string _ws.col.Info=58842 ÔåÆ 3389 Len=12
```

Above you see the several properties that you could use for further filtering, sorting (e.g. `$result | Sort-Object ip.dst`) or to select the several properties via the `Format-Table` cmdlet.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $result[0] | Format-Table -Property frame.number, ip.dst, ip.src

frame.number ip.dst      ip.src
------------ ------      ------
1            10.22.23.98 172.22.21.50
```

Hope that helps.